# angular:create model named Heros.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I work on Angular 5, I have the below JSON named heros and I have to create model class for it.

```
[{
    "data": {
        "name": "adsd0 ",
        "lastName": "",
        "isNode": true
    },
    "children": [{
        "data": {
            "name": "",
            "lastName": ""
        }
    }]
}]
```

So far what I did is below after which I got stuck

```
export class Heros{
 data:string;
children:Child[];

export class Child{

}
```

Can anyone please guide me how to move ahead, I am not getting how to create a model

Answer (score 2):

Try the below structure,

```
export class Heros {
  data: Data;
  children: Array<Children>;
}

export class Data {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
  isNode: boolean;
}

export class Children {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I could generate from an [online JSON to TS converter](https://jvilk.com/MakeTypes/). You may want to clean it up a bit though, like making `Data` and `Data1` use a same class making `isNode` optional. Converter can come in handy when you have to do a lot of this.

Also you may want to make these as `class` instead of `interface` if what you want is `class`.

```
export interface Hero {
  data: Data;
  children?: (ChildrenEntity)[] | null;
}
export interface Data {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
  isNode: boolean;
}
export interface ChildrenEntity {
  data: Data1;
}
export interface Data1 {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface Weather {
  data: Data;
  children?: (ChildrenEntity)[] | null;
}
export interface Data {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
  isNode: boolean;
}
export interface ChildrenEntity {
  data: Data1;
}
export interface Data1 {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
}

export class ClassName  {
 dataarray:Weather[];
}
```